# Triggering .has-error class of bootstrap using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form using bootstrap like this -

```
<form id="depot-submit-form">

   <div class="form-group row has-error">
       <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Name</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter the name of the depot here">
       </div>
   </div>
  .............
</form>
```

*My form has the **.has-error** class of bootstrap.*

I am checking if any input field is kept empty in case of submission of the form. Here is my code for checking it ---

```
$(function() {
  $("#depot-submit-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#depot-submit-form").serializeArray();
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].value.length == 0){
            ---- some codes here ---
        }
    }
  });
});
```

My first question is, how can i access the bootstrap **.has-error** class when a submitted field is found empty in the section described as **some codes here**?

Normally, **.has-error** class will make the empty input field **red.** I want to throw an error message also. My second question is, can i do that with the help of jquery ?

Comment: validate the input values, not the serialized disconnected data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first question is, how can i access the bootstrap .has-error class when a submitted field is found empty in the section described as some codes here?

Since you have the indexes in the loop may be you can try accessing the input elements by index, and then trace top to find the `has-error` element. So you can do this, `But this is not 100% accurate if your there is a mismatch in the number of input and the wrapping div's`

```
 $(function() {
  $("#depot-submit-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#depot-submit-form").serializeArray();
    var allInputs = $("#depot-submit-form input");
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        if(data[i].value.length == 0){
            var currErrorDiv = $(allInputs)[i].closest('.has-error'); // this will give the corresponding div of the empty field input
        }
    }
  });
});
```

> Normally, .has-error class will make the empty input field red. I want to throw an error message also. My second question is, can i do that with the help of jquery ?

You can simply loop through all the div's which has the class `has-error` and append a error message too. Like below

```
$('.has-error').each(function(){
  $(this).find('.col-sm-10').append("<span>Error in this Input!!!</span>");
});
```

---

**Better Approach:**

But I don't think the way you are doing is efficient by playing with the serilized data. Here is my suggestion. Combing both your questions

```
 $(function() {
  $("#depot-submit-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
      if($(this).val().length == 0){            
         $("<span>Error in this Input!!!</span>").insertAfter( $(this));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Or by looping on the class `has-class`

```
 $(function() {
  $("#depot-submit-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.has-error').each(function(){                  
         $(this).find('.col-md-10').append("<span>Error in this Input!!!</span>");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need help in another case related to it. It seems .has-error class is making my input fields red even before submitting anything.

Comment: I think it is happening real time, like as soon as the focus goes out of the input element you might be getting the input as red right?

Comment: Whenever, i load the page, i am getting fields as red. Before inserting any input. You can check live version of it here - http://ni8mr.github.io/gpsl-ui/  Click "Add new depot" button.

Comment: why is the class `has-error` already applied to all your div's?? have you added that class in your HTML?

Comment: hmmm, glad you found out :)

Comment: Just another question, i am trying to add has-error class now after adding error message  with this code- **$('input').addClass("has-error"); **, as i need to make the input field red. Am i doing it ok ? Cause i am not seeing any changes in the box while submitting.

Comment: you need to add it to the div which wraps the input and not the input.. So add the class to the div with the classes `form-group row `

Comment: Tried with this code but didn't get any output- $("form-group row").addClass("has-error");

Comment: `$(input).closest(".form-group.row").addClass("has-error");` use this

Comment: It is making all the fields red. Can i make a specific field red (empty field)? I am sorry, if i am making this discussion longer.

Comment: when are you executing this script. you need to slecete the specific div and add the class

Comment: I have put the code inside if($(this).val().length == 0){} statement, which was checking for empty value.

Comment: then use this `$(this).closest(".form-group.row").addClass("has-error");`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if any of your divs inside the form has error with:

```
if ($("#depo-submit-form .has-error").length > 0)
```

or just:

```
$("#depot-submit-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#depo-submit-form .has-error").each(function() {
    ---- some codes here ---
  });
  var data = $("#depot-submit-form").serializeArray();
});
```

You can check after serializeArray, but it would be easier to do so earlier.

> I want to throw[show] an error message also.

Add your message in a div and use css:

```
<form id="depot-submit-form">
    <div class="form-group row has-error">
        <div class="errmessage">Message</div>
```

css:

```
.errmessage { display:none; }
.has-error .errmessage { display:inline; }
```

Comment: Ok, i am going to try that.

Comment: Will .errmessage class will be triggered by default when i access .has-error class ?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense.  "triggered" when "access".  The css I've provided will show the message/hide the message automatically when you add/remove `.has-error` on a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (not tested)?

```
$(function() {
    $("#depot-submit-form").submit(function(e) {

        // get the form fields
        var formFields = $("#depot-submit-form input"),
            invalidCount = 0;

        // loop through them
        formFields.forEach(function(formField) {
            var isEmpty = formField.value === '';

            // add or remove `has-error` class if value is empty
            $(formField).toggleClass('has-error', isEmpty);

            if (isEmpty) {
                invalidCount++;
            }
        });

        // only prevent submitting if there are empty inputs
        if (invalidCount > 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });
});
```